# « Désirer se rencontrer » : quel pronom choisir ?

Tags: pronoms

Dans un scénario ou deux personnes veulent se rencontrer, quelle est la bonne façon de mettre le verbe pronominal « désirer se rencontrer » au pluriel ?

> À quelle heure désires-tu se rencontrer ?
>   À quelle heure désires-tu nous rencontrer ?

J'essaye de ne pas avoir à recourir à « À quelle heure désires-tu qu'on se rencontre », si c'est possible ?

Comment: La seconde proposition n'est pas incorrecte si l'on parle de trois personnes, ou plus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Les deux premières formes sont incorrectes; « désires-tu se rencontrer » est impossible et
 « désires-tu nous rencontrer » implique qu'il y a plus de deux personnes.

Voici quelques propositions :

- À quelle heure désires-tu me rencontrer ?
- À quelle heure désires-tu que nous nous rencontrions ?
- À quelle heure désires-tu que l'on se rencontre ?

Plutôt que « Désirer », j'aurais mis « souhaiter » ou « vouloir » dans ce contexte.

Une façon informelle de poser cette question:

- On se voit à quelle heure ?

Answer (score 2):

Je dirai :

À quelle heure désires-tu que nous nous rencontrions ?

ou bien :

À quelle heure désires-tu *me* rencontrer ?